# Selecting data from a table in one sql query with 'special' WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems selecting the right data from a table with one query. I'm
unsure if it can be done.

```
properties:
- id
- name

facilities:
- id
- name

property_facilities:
- property_id
- facility_id
```

As you can see in the schema above, each property can have one or more
facilities. At a certain point in my code I need to have a list of property ids
that have some facilities.

PSEUDO SQL:

```
SELECT property_id
FROM property_facilities
WHERE
  facility_id IN (8, 12)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, since I need to have a list of property ids that
have BOTH the facility 8 and 12, not just one of them. How could I achieve
this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a HAVING clause with the expected number of matching id's will do it:

```
SELECT property_id
FROM property_facilities
WHERE facility_id IN (8, 12)
GROUP BY property_id
HAVING count(facility_id) = 2
```

This does assume, however, that you have no duplicate entries in your `property_facilities` table.  If you do, you can fix this using DISTINCT in a subquery, or by simply adding constraints not to allow duplicates in the first place.

Here's the same query with a DISTINCT subquery:

```
SELECT property_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT property_id, facility_id FROM property_facilities) distinct_rows
WHERE facility_id IN (8, 12)
GROUP BY property_id
HAVING count(facility_id) = 2
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I still get property ids that have facility 8 but not 12.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be including `facility_id` in your SELECT clause since the row represents multiple `facility_id`s.  If you want, you can `SELECT property_id, count(facility_id)` to see how many matching rows it finds.  Secondly, can you verify if you have duplicate rows in your table or not?

Comment: Yes, the property 1249 has both facility 8 and 12. I added the facility_id to the query just to show the results because I was not getting the expected results.

Comment: For a property that has only 8 or 12 but not both, can you check if there are multiple such rows in the table?  For instance, `SELECT * FROM property_facilities WHERE property_id = 123` (assuming 123 doesn't have both). Using the DISTINCT subquery should help for this (added above).

Comment: I can confirm your query works as intended. Thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> select property_id from properties where property_id in 
>     (select property_id from property_facilities)

That will generate a list of all property ids that have any facilities, not just 8 or 12

EDIT: If you're trying to grab a list of properties that have facilities 8 and 12 you can do the following:

```
select property_id from properties where property_id in 
(select property_id from property_facilities where facility_id = 8) and property_id in
(select property_id from property_facilities where facility_id = 12)
```